# What is the purpose of AbstractCollection

Tags: java

`AbstractCollection` implements `Collection`. So why is `AbstractCollection` there and why do we use `Collection` instead of directly using `AbstractCollection`?

Comment: It doesn't _just_ implements `Collection`.

Comment: AbstractCollection is a hell of a less noisy to read at a glance.

Comment: Typically, abstract implementations define some of the common functionality which likely going to be used by most if not all other implementations, it's there to make your life easier, but you don't need to use it

Comment: Line 1 of [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) answers your question: "This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Collection interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this interface."

Comment: @Boann And what that implies is that some collection implementations will NOT be using `AbstractCollection` because they will provide their own implementation of all the methods defined in the `Collection` interface. For example, Guava's `ForwardingList`

Comment: Abstract Classes show us the path to how to implement the interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it is a little late to answer but just in case I want to answer this question.

1. `AbstractCollection` is used since all the child collections share some functionalities in common as Krzysztof said and, since this functionality is common (exactly the same lines of code) we can use inheritance to rehuse that code and make the design cleaner, easier to understand and more maintainable.
2. We use the interface since an interface defines the "contract" that every class implementing the interface must provide, i.e the methods that the subclasses must have. This question is similar to, why can't we use `ArrayList` instead of List, you can do that, but 90% of the times you will be interested on adding/setting, deleting and knowing the size of an `ArrayList` and the `List` interface assures you that anything that is written after a new somewhere will implement this methods (and others) so you can call them and polymorphism will do the work. Also, using the interface as a reference allows you to change the type of the concrete implementation without changing anything (only the new calls) and also allows you to change the specific type at runtime, using the specific class reference you are constraining yourself to that reference and only that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Angelixus says in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58513874/139985:

One reason to NOT do this:

```
AbstractCollection col = (AbstractCollection) someCollection;
```

is that subtypes of `Collection` are NOT guaranteed to extend the `AbstractCollection` base class.

It is certainly the case that most (if not all) of the standard collection types do extend this base class.  However, this may not apply to all 3rd-party collection classes.  If you encounter a collection class that is implemented without extending `AbstractCollection`, the above will give either a compilation error or a runtime exception, depending on the *declared* type of `someCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` interface declares useful methods that all implementing classes must supply. But it is a bother if every class that implements the `Collection` interface has to supply so many methods.

To make life easier for us, the library supplies a class `AbstractCollection` that leaves the fundamental methods `size` and `iterator` abstract but implements the routine methods in terms of them. For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractCollection<E>
    implements Collection<E>
{
    ...
    public abstract Iterator<E> iterator();
    public boolean contains(Object obj)
    {
        for (E element : this) // calls iterator()
            if (element.equals(obj))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Concrete collection class can now extend the `AbstractCollection` class. It is up to us now to supply `iterator` method, but the `contains` method has been taken care of by the `AbstractCollection` superclass. However, if the subclass has a more efficient way of implementing `contains`, it is free to do so. **But this approach is a bit outdated**.

Answer (score 0):

Code is best documentation out there :-) Source can be checked in JDK, and for example in [code-grep pages](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java).

And there you one can see, that `AbstractCollection` class (at least in java 6b-14) offers straight-forward implementations of `isEmpty()`, `contains()`,  `toArray()`, `toArray(T[] a)`, `remove(Object o)`, `containsAll(Collection<?> c)` `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`, `removeAll(Collection<?> c)`, `retainAll(Collection<?> c)`, `clear()` and `toString()`.

Mentioned methods depend on implementations of `add(E e)`, `iterator()` and (optionally) `remove(Object o)`.

Answer (score 0):

These classes are called **skeletal implementation** classes. Naming convention is Abstract*Interface* where interface is the name of the interface (eg - AbstractList). They are created by combining interfaces and abstract classes.

Generally when we design an interface and when there is obvious implementation to the interface methods, we can provide the default methods in the interface so that the person who implements the interface can follow the default implementation and provide the custom implementation on top of it. But there are limits on how much implementation assistance you can provide with default methods. A reason is interfaces are not permitted to contain instance fields or nonpublic static members. We can however combine the advantages of interfaces and abstract classes.

Refer to the example below. Suppose we have method which accept int array and return a List of Integers which contains square of each elements.

```
public static List<Integer> squaredList(int [] e) {
    
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return e[index] * e[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return e.length;
        }
    };
}
```

AbstractCollection, 2 methods are abstract. If you want
To implement an unmodifiable collection, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the iterator and size methods. (The iterator returned by the iterator method must implement hasNext and next.)
These type of implementation is very useful when you are implementing an immutable classes which has a method to return a Collection.

To implement a modifiable collection, the programmer must additionally override this class's add method (which otherwise throws an UnsupportedOperationException), and the iterator returned by the iterator method must additionally implement its remove method.

Refer the java docs for additional info
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting quote worth referencing from [Core Java, Volume I―Fundamentals, 10th Edition](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/core-java-r-volume/9780134177335/ch06.html#:-:text=In%20the%20Java%20API%2C%20you%20will,methods%20in%20the%20interface.):

> In the Java API, you will find a number of interfaces with companion classes that implement some or all of its methods, such as `Collection`/`AbstractCollection` or `MouseListener`/`MouseAdapter`. With Java SE 8, this technique is obsolete. Just implement the methods in the interface.